# Ruby undefined method `write' for IO:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, io, nomethoderror

when i run my ruby file

```
ruby test.rb
```

which has one line:

```
IO.write("testfile.txt","123")
```

i get

```
test.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined method `write' for IO:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what kind of answer do you expect? `IO` does not have any class method called `write`. At most it has `binwrite` and an *instance* method `#write`.

So either you use `binwrite` (http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/IO.binwrite) or you use the `File` class and go the full way of

```
File.open("testfile.txt", "w") { |f| f << "123" }
```

**Edit:** Apparently there is an `IO.write` method beginning with Ruby 1.9.3. There is, however, no such method in any earlier versions of 1.9 or 1.8.

Comment: Thank you! I was reading the 1.9.3 rubydoc and used ruby 1.9.2, it works nice now after an update. How can you see at which version a method is introduced?

Comment: The documentation doesn't include any clues on that. The only way is to read changelogs of new releases, or those aggregated "What's changed" blog posts, even though those can be incomplete.

Comment: @cande apidock.com is very helpful.  It shows when methods were added/changed and also allows people to leave comments/tips about their use.  For IO.write its http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/IO/write/class

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues,

1. IO does not have a class method write and that it why you are seeing the exception
2. If you want to write to a file you should use the File class

   File.open("testfile.txt", "w") do |file|
       file.write("123")
   end

I think you're probably just getting started with Ruby so it may be a good idea to read up a book on ruby which will show some of these basics. I have used "The Ruby Programming Language" by David Flanagan and Matz, but quite a few people have used what is called the Pickaxe book or "Programming Ruby" by Dave Thomas, Chad Fowler and Andy Hunt.